# SQL Sum of Values when ID's columns can be reversed

Tags: mysql, sql

Not entirely sure on the title for this question but I've been stumped by this for a couple of hours now with no success in searching for similar questions or posts.

Essentially I have 3 columns in TableA as shown below:

```
**| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |**
  |  1   |   2  |  50  |
  |  1   |   3  |  64  |
  |  2   |   1  |  71  |
  |  2   |   5  |  16  |
  |  5   |   2  |  23  |
```

`Col1 is a SourceID, Col2 is a TargetID and Col3 is the Value`

Col1 and Col2 are ID's referenced from another table. The Col1 and Col2 must not be the same in the same record, so Col1 can't be `1` as well as Col2 being `1` at the same time. However as you can see from records 1 and 3, they are referencing the same two ID's however they've swapped Columns.

Now my question is this: How do I get the total Value for each ID as seen in the table below:

```
**| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |**
  |  1   |   2  |  121 |
  |  1   |   3  |  64  |
  |  2   |   5  |  39  |
```

The Col3 Value with will be the SUM of all the Values with matching ID's (whether or not the ID appeared in Col1 or Col2), They will be ordered by Col1 ASC. This essetianlly means that the two records below were removed:

```
  |  2   |   1  |  71  |
  |  5   |   2  |  23  |
```

I'm happy to add extra info where needed however it's been quite a difficult problem to describe- Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `least` and `greatest`.

```
select least(col1,col2),greatest(col1,col2),sum(col3)
from tbl 
group by least(col1,col2),greatest(col1,col2)
```

Note that this might give you row combinations that aren't in the table. You should clarify if you have to avoid such cases.

Comment: That looks like it solves it, Thanks Vamsi! 
When you say that it may produce combinations that aren't in the table, could you clarify on the sort of edge cases that could come up?

Comment: for instance if you have a row `5,4,10`..the output would show up as `4,5,10` because there is no corresponding symmetric pair.

Comment: Ah I see, well the ordering itself wouldn't be too problematic however it would only cause an issue if the value of 5 and 4 or 4 and 5 were different some how

Comment: To clairfy, if 4 and 5 were 100 and it showed up as 5 and 4 instead but still showed as 100 then this would be acceptable